# Angular -> build object from localstorage data where localstorage data is consisting of multiple keys and values

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, rest

How to build single object from localstorage where localstorage data is consisting of multiple localstorage keys and values ?

That object will be then saved to firebase with REST post method.

What I have:

1. Multistep form consisting of 8 steps (last 9th step 'summary' only for saving)
2. Each step is a separate component with separate reactive form
3. Data from each form is saved as a localstorage draft as: a) key -> title of the step b) value -> stringified JSON.stringify(value)
4. Question: How to save those steps stored in localstorage as a single object called PROMOTION inside the database (Firebase) ?"

After building the object I will be able to save that object into the firebase with post method.

Multistep form:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hhg5a.jpg)

The image presenting localstorage data:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5TRD.jpg)

**Simplified code** -> https://pastecode.io/s/e1gyjxws

**Github repo** -> https://github.com/RobotHabanera/august2023

My attempt was to make **create()** method inside Create Service which would loop through enum values which are matching each consesutive localstorage key and collect data to

First, I created Enum which was refered at different stages i.e saving drafts to localstorage and now I want to use that enum to gather data to build object:

Steps Enum: https://pastecode.io/s/7rh9cnat

My attempt to create such object:

```
create(draft:DraftService) {
    // 1. loop through each localstorage draft
    // var keys = Object.values(this.stepsEnum);
    // keys.forEach((item) => {
    //   const data = draft.getLocalStorageData(item);
    //   console.log(data);
    //   // 2. if given key is not empty save to the database
    //   // 3. if saved then clear the draft
    //   // 4. redirect
    // });

    this.stepsEnum.forEach(item => {
      // zbuduj obiekt wykorzystujący klasę
      // 2. if given key is not empty save to the database
      let definition;
      let choose_products;
      let exclude_products;
      let bonus_products;
      let products_limits;
      let choose_clients;
      let exclude_clients;
      let clients_limits;

      if (item === 'definition') {
        definition = draft.getLocalStorageData(item);
      }
      if (item === 'choose-products') {
        choose_products = draft.getLocalStorageData(item);
      }
      if (item === 'exclude-products') {
        exclude_products = draft.getLocalStorageData(item);
      }
      if (item === 'bonus-products') {
        bonus_products = draft.getLocalStorageData(item);
      }
      if (item === 'products-limits') {
        products_limits = draft.getLocalStorageData(item);
      }
      if (item === 'choose-clients') {
        choose_clients = draft.getLocalStorageData(item);
      }
      if (item === 'exclude-clients') {
        exclude_clients = draft.getLocalStorageData(item);
      }
      if (item === 'clients-limits') {
        clients_limits = draft.getLocalStorageData(item);
      }

      this.promotion = new Promotion(
        definition,
        choose_products,
        exclude_products,
        bonus_products,
        products_limits,
        choose_clients,
        exclude_clients,
        clients_limits
      )

    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will want to do something more like this. What you have now will create a new `Promotion` on each iteration of the loop, I assume you only want to do this one time.

- Iterate of `Object.keys(StepsEnum)` instead of the enum directly, which I don't think will work anyway
- The variables are created once outside of the loop
- Now using `else` statements inside the loop is a minor performance improvement since there can only be one match per loop iteration anyway (and this makes for fewer lines of code)
- Then, after the looping completes, create the `Promotion` object one time now that all the variables should be defined

```ts
let definition;
let choose_products;
let exclude_products;
let bonus_products;
let products_limits;
let choose_clients;
let exclude_clients;
let clients_limits;

Object.keys(StepsEnum)
  .forEach((enumKey: string) => {
    if (enumKey === 'definition') {
      definition = draft.getLocalStorageData(enumKey);
    } else if (enumKey === 'choose-products') {
      choose_products = draft.getLocalStorageData(enumKey);
    } else  if (enumKey === 'exclude-products') {
      exclude_products = draft.getLocalStorageData(enumKey);
    } else  if (enumKey === 'bonus-products') {
      bonus_products = draft.getLocalStorageData(enumKey);
    } else  if (enumKey === 'products-limits') {
      products_limits = draft.getLocalStorageData(enumKey);
    } else  if (enumKey === 'choose-clients') {
      choose_clients = draft.getLocalStorageData(enumKey);
    } else  if (enumKey === 'exclude-clients') {
      exclude_clients = draft.getLocalStorageData(enumKey);
    } else  if (enumKey === 'clients-limits') {
      clients_limits = draft.getLocalStorageData(enumKey);
    }
  });

this.promotion = new Promotion(
  definition,
  choose_products,
  exclude_products,
  bonus_products,
  products_limits,
  choose_clients,
  exclude_clients,
  clients_limits
)
```

---

Even simpler though, since you already know the values you want to get, just skip the variables, looping, and enum entirely. Just pass in what you want when you create the object.

```ts
this.promotion = new Promotion(
  draft.getLocalStorageData('definition'),
  draft.getLocalStorageData('choose-products'),
  draft.getLocalStorageData('exclude-products'),
  draft.getLocalStorageData('bonus-products'),
  draft.getLocalStorageData('products-limits'),
  draft.getLocalStorageData('choose-clients'),
  draft.getLocalStorageData('exclude-clients'),
  draft.getLocalStorageData('clients-limits'),
)
```

to add null checks, you could do this:

```ts
this.promotion = new Promotion(
  draft.getLocalStorageData('definition') ?? {},
  draft.getLocalStorageData('choose-products') ?? {},
  draft.getLocalStorageData('exclude-products') ?? {},
  draft.getLocalStorageData('bonus-products') ?? {},
  draft.getLocalStorageData('products-limits') ?? {},
  draft.getLocalStorageData('choose-clients') ?? {},
  draft.getLocalStorageData('exclude-clients') ?? {},
  draft.getLocalStorageData('clients-limits') ?? {},
)
```

Comment: Thanks, that simpler approach at the end is the way to go. The only improvement, since data from localstorage coluld be null, is to do the following to each line (first line as an example):
JSON.parse(draft.getLocalStorageData('definition') || '{}')

Comment: Yep, that's probably a good idea to do anyway if you want to avoid `null` everywhere else that also uses `getLocalStorageData`. If you do want `null`s elsewhere though you could move that check to where the `Promotion` object is created. See my updated answer for that. However your way is probably cleaner since you only have to do that once.